# GridView not showing records in uwp

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp

I am working on a uwp app. I am not following MVVM in this context. Thing is I am getting json data from a url and parsing it using Newtonsoft and want to bind it to the DataGrid control. Problem is the datagrid doesn't show up at all. On page load I am populating the collectionviewsource using Dispatcher and binding to the GridView. But doesn't help. Please help.

XAML:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0" Margin="20">
            <TextBlock Text="Search:"></TextBlock>
            <TextBox Height="30" Width="140" Margin="20,0,0,0"></TextBox>
        </StackPanel>

        <GridView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding viewSource.View}" Height="500" SelectionMode="Single" Width="Auto">
            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding recordID}"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding allergy_name}"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding reaction}"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding allergy_date}"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding severity}"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding status}"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        </GridView>
</Grid>
```

Here is my XAML.cs

```
TwoFactor factor;
public CollectionViewSource viewSource { get; set; }
        private List<AllergyRecord> _allergyrecords;
        public List<AllergyRecord> AllAllergies
        {
            get
            {
                return _allergyrecords;
            }
            set { _allergyrecords = value; }
        }
        public AddAllergy()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent(); 
            this.DataContext = this;
            viewSource = new CollectionViewSource();
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
            factor = (TwoFactor)e.Parameter;
        }

        public async Task<string> jsonResult(string url)
        {
            string data;
            var client = new HttpClient();
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
            using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
            {
                data = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }

            return data;
        }



        private async void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            AllAllergies = new List<AllergyRecord>();
            string json = await jsonResult("http://ec2-54-83-191-130.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080/Sanjeevani/rest/SV/GetAllergy/" + factor.Passcode);
            RootObject data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);

            foreach (var item in data.AllergyRecords)
            {
                AllAllergies.Add(item);
            }
            Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
() =>
{
    viewSource.Source = AllAllergies;
});

        }
    }
```

Here is my Root Object class.

```
public class AllergyRecord
    {
        public string allergy_date { get; set; }
        public string allergy_name { get; set; }
        public string reaction { get; set; }
        public string recordID { get; set; }
        public string severity { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public List<AllergyRecord> AllergyRecords { get; set; }
        public string ForceLogOn { get; set; }
        public string returnCode { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that `factor.Passcode` has good value, becase I think `OnNavigatedTo` called after `Page_Loaded` event handler.

Comment: Yes I kept breakpoints and data gets perfectly populated in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here are the steps that I did. In case it helps someone. First of here is my XAML change for the gridview part.

```
<GridView x:Name="grdData" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{x:Bind AllAllergies}" Height="300" SelectionMode="Single" Width="Auto" Background="AliceBlue">
            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:AllergyRecord">
                    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind recordID}"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind allergy_name}"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind reaction}"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind allergy_date}"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind severity}"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind status}"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        </GridView>
```

And the change I did in my XAML.cs is

Commented out this.DataContext=this line below the Initialize component all together and at the end in the async page load I just said this.Bindings.Update(); as the last line and it works. Here is the same type of problem and answer.
[Data not displaying (C# UWP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39165185/data-not-displaying-c-uwp)

Comment: For me, just changing 'ItemsSource="{Binding viewSource.View}"' to 'ItemsSource="{x:Bind AllAllergies}"' worked.

Answer (score -1):

Since you mentioned MVVM, I would suggest a MVVM Pattern answer.

First off you need to move your Web Calls to a ViewModel Class. So Below is how it would look.

```cs
public class AllAllergiesViewModel
{
    public RootObject rootObject { get; set; }
    public async Task GetAllAllergies()
    {
        string json = await jsonResult("http://ec2-54-83-191-130.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080/Sanjeevani/rest/SV/GetAllergy/" + factor.Passcode);
        this.rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
    }

    internal async Task<string> jsonResult(string url)
    {
        string data;
        var client = new HttpClient();
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
        using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
        {
            data = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

Your `RootObject` will look like below.

```cs
public class RootObject
{
    public ObservableCollection<AllergyRecord> AllergyRecords { get; set; }
    public string ForceLogOn { get; set; }
    public string returnCode { get; set; }
}
```

In your `MainPage_Loaded`, you can use `DataContext` like below.

```cs
private async void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var viewModel = new AllAllergiesViewModel();
    grdData.DataContext = viewModel;
    await viewModel.GetAllAllergies();
}
```

And your XAML will be

```xml
<GridView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding AllergyRecords}" Height="500" SelectionMode="Single" Width="Auto" x:Name="grdData">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding recordID}"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding allergy_name}"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding reaction}"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding allergy_date}"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding severity}"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding status}"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

Comment: I know how to do it using MVVM but the problem is how do I implement OnNavigatedTo in the viewmodel. It doesn't allow me/

Comment: The question was not about MVVM patterns!